# Showing a PNG from bytes inside a <image> SVG element

Tags: html, svg

I cannot figure out how to do this. I have a PNG file in the following Base64 encoded format:

```
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
```

I'm trying to show this in an `<image>` element, but it seems it only has the `href` attribute and no way to show it from bytes like `<img>` does. Is there any workaround on this or am I stuck with the HTML `<img>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a data uri as the href.

Since you are dealing with a base 64 representation of a PNG; you would prefix the string with `data:image/png;base64,`

Using your image data as an example:

```html
<svg width="100px" height="100px" version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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" x="0" y="0" height="100px" width="100px"/>
</svg>
```